# C++ gnu gcc compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, gnu

I am currently in the process of switching compilers.

From microtech to GNU GCC/G++ coldfire..

I keep receiving the following error and can not find a simple solution:

warning: ANSI C++ forbids declaration `interrupt' with no type

I know the line that it is failing on:

friend interrupt void IrqCtmMCSM2(void);

Could someone offer suggestions please?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `interrupt` is not a [C++ keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), I think it must have been a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: solution: friend __attribute__((interrupt)) void IrqCtmMCSM2(void);